Application scrollbar not showing in FlutterFlow
I am trying to enable the application scrollbar using FlutterFlow.
However, despite my best efforts, the scrollbar remains elusive.
When it does materialise, it is a rudimentary version - grey, diminutive and often indiscernible.
Curiously, the default scrollbar is absent on certain pages, that should need her (not sure, but I can't see her on some pages).
When conducting my tests, I utilise a page that boasts a substantial Widgets Tree, resulting in the need for scrolling.
To summarise this page in a more succinct manner :
- Stack
-- Column (primary, with many sub widgets)
-- FAB
Home Page Widget Tree
My test phone is a Samsung Galaxy A12, but I know that it is the same issue on iPhones.
I set the section "Scrollbar Theme" (under "Theme Settings") with the following :
- Thumb Color : red
- Track Color : Gray (alpha 50%)
- Thickness : 9
- Border Radius : 0
- Thumb Always Visible : true
- Track Visible : true
- Interactive : false
Scrollbar Theme settings
Based on the official documentation : FlutterFlow Documentation
I searched for settings that I could miss, but nothing found.
I searched throught multiple forums, and online tutorials but I didn't found anything usefull.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
